# Cannot update JDK location in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot update the Java JDK or Android SDK path in Android Studio.

**To update the default JDK or Android SDK:**

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to Quick Start -> Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
3. Change the JDK location

**My problem/question:**

The "Apply" button isn't clickable and if I press "OK" the JDK or Android SDK locations are never updated. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yn0AgRb4wQ&feature=youtu.be) showing what happens when I try to update the location. How can I fix this?

**Expected results:**

Android Studio should update the JDK and/or SDK locations.

**Additional info:**

`JAVA_HOME` environment variable matches the location I am trying to update in Android Studio.

Android Studio 1.5.1 Build 141.2456560

Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Have you tried from File Menu?

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes, I have. I figured out a solution and posted it as an answer. You cannot accept your own answer before 2 days. I'll leave the post up and hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a warning about the Android SDK location having spaces in the path. Once I moved the SDK to a location without spaces and updated the SDK location in Android Studio I was then able to update the Java JDK location using the steps outlined in the question above.

This may be a more common problem in the future since the Android SDK Windows installer will always place the Android SDK in a directory with spaces ("Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)").