# Android studio is always using JDK 7 and don't switch to JDK 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have encountered some interesting problem.

When I try to change JDK by clicking to **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location**:

[image: Opended SDK Location]

I change it to my new version:

[image: Changed SDK]

Then I click **OK** then open this page again, it shows me this:

[image: Whiskey Tango Foxtrot!]

Why does not want to change JDK?! Even my PATH is set to JDK 8

My version of Android studio is 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to these answer i think that it will be very useful for you :

[Android Studio JDK location changes back to 1.7 every time it is updated to 1.8 path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066957/android-studio-jdk-location-changes-back-to-1-7-every-time-it-is-updated-to-1-8)