# PyCharm Embedded Terminal Points to Different Python

Tags: macos, pycharm

[image: Terminal Python path pic]

[image: Pycharm-Embedded Terminal Python path pic]

Currently using mac osx. I am curious as to why these terminals are pointing to different pythons, i.e. the iTerm -> Homebrew python, whereas Pycharm-embeeded-terminal -> Apple-provided python.

[Pycharm's terminal doesn't change the Python version corresponding to Python version at Project Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237346/pycharms-terminal-doesnt-change-the-python-version-corresponding-to-python-ver)

seems closest to my question, but but not quite in that the os there is Windows and the solution doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but with Android Studio, which is also IntelliJ based IDE. You should edit some files in your IDE's settings manually

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952739/android-studio-is-always-using-jdk-7-and-dont-switch-to-jdk-8)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066957/android-studio-jdk-location-changes-back-to-1-7-every-time-it-is-updated-to-1-8)

Then you should restart your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But it seems like the jdk.table.xml correctly points to the brew python, as I would wish. I tried deleting it, correctly set up the path and restarted the ide but did not solve the problem