# Android Studio is NOT detecting my newest version of JDK, and instead using my old one >:(

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

Ok so anyone answering please be aware that I am a complete beginner to all of this. But I have installed jdk1.8.0 because that is what the newest version of android studio needs, but when I open Android studio up, it says I still need to change it. So after a lot of research I made a new Java_Home variable and set the directory to where my jdk file was. I then went into android studio file, project structure, then changed that jdk directory as well. However, when I click ok, It still doesn't work, and when I go back to the project structure, it changes from jdk version 8, to my old jdk version 7 directory. For some reason it isn't saving :(. I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: If the answer solved it you can mark it as correct (green check)

Comment: dont get why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable the old JDK in the *"Java Control Panel" (JCPL)*. Start the JCPL by double-clicking on *jre\bin\javacpl.exe* (it's a Swing application, i.e. it has a GUI). Choose tab *"Java"* and click on the button *"View ..."* to see a table with all installed JDKs. Each JDK has a checkbox *"Enabled"*, which should be unchecked for the old JDK.

When you restart *Android Studio* after this it should ask you for the path of the JDK.

The following question might also be helpful to solve this issue: [Android Studio JDK location changes back to 1.7 every time it is updated to 1.8 path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066957/)

Comment: Isn't the referenced answer a *duplicate*?

Comment: OMG YES thank you so much! I was so dumb I had installed a jdk(x86) when my system was x64!  The link you sent me also helped too! Appreciate the help, can finally start coding again :)